# Custom icon set not displaying in Safari

Tags: css, sass, fonts, safari

I created some icons using FontForge, and the icons work in all modern browsers except for Safari. What would be causing Safari to be the only browser that doesn't display the fonts?

This is the SCSS that is being used:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFont.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.my-font-icon {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    display: inline-block;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

    &:before {
        font-family: 'MyFont';
        display: inline-block;
        speak: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        text-rendering: auto;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

    &.my-font-questions:before {
        content: "\0001";
    }
    &.my-font-chevron-left:before {
        content: "\0002";
    }
    &.my-font-close:before {
        content: "\0003";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the font loaded in Safari e.g. is the font listed as http 200 response in the networks tab ?

Comment: @anderssonola yes it is getting loaded with a `200`.

Answer (score 0):

Safari requires the TrueType/ttf font version and really you should be including several different types rather than just woff2 which is the most modern type. Here's a sample list from the CSS Tricks article [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/), the browser finds the font it understands and renders that one:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

FontForge should provide you these other font types, but if it doesn't, you'll need to go to FontSquirrel to render them (if you have the licence and permission to do so):

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: woff2 is fully supported in Safari from v12 ?

Comment: It should be supported, and we are having issues with it in v13.

Comment: We have tried using your above solution, but it didn't work. The icon still doesn't show. It shows up as an empty space.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn is your font file in the right place?

Comment: Looks like FontForge has a checker, has your font passed the proper checks? http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Making_Sure_Your_Font_Works_Validation.html @GetOffMyLawn

Comment: @anderssonola you're right, since v12 fully supported: http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Making_Sure_Your_Font_Works_Validation.html Still good to have the fallbacks, though. :)

Comment: Sure, but most modern font generators generates woff + woff2 now days and that would cover the mot browsers used today.